# c# check if a string starts and ends with a char, by using its ascii code

Tags: c#, string, ascii

How can I check if a string in c# starts with an ascii code of a char?
The function StartsWith recieves only a string and not a char.
I want to know if the string starts with the ascii of 86 and ends with an ascii of 91.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use regex to check this

Answer (score 6):

You can check the begin and end by accessing the char array of the string:

```
string s = "...";

if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) && 
    (s[0] == (char)86) && (s[s.Length-1] == (char)91))
    // doSomething
```

Comment: better include a check, if s.Length > 0 or s[0] might fail.

Comment: -1 You don't need to cast an integer to a char for this operation.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I know but I'm prefering it for readability (no impact on anything else)

Comment: That is arguably far less readable than not casting. It looks like a jumbled mess.

Comment: @DavidAnderson without wanting to argue with you (I clearly see your point) I would insert some spacing... But I won't force you to include the explicit cast ;-)

Comment: There's no need to argue since everyone is entitled an opinion. Most teams won't pass that through code review because you're missing spacing, brackets, and have unnecessary code. I think its important that developers promote high quality, well constructed code, especially to those learning and entering the industry.

Comment: As usual this depends heavily on the team contract one may have designed as you should being part of a bigger team. And learning should involve a process and not permanently being confronted with absolute perfect solutions... Others use StyleCop or similar tools and enforce a totally ridiculous "code convention". But ok.

Answer (score 5):

You can use string.Startswith like

```
bool success = yourString.StartsWith(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(86))
               && yourString.EndsWith(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(91));
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to a char, then to a string.

```
((char) 86).ToString()
```

Or, just check the string direct:

```
mystring[0] == (char) 86
```

Or:

```
mystring[0] == '\x56' // in hex
```

Or even:

```
mystring.StartsWith("\x56")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare characters to their ASCII code directly, without a cast:

```
if (str.Length != 0 && str[0] == 86 && str[str.Length-1] == 91) ...
```

Of course character constants look better in their natural form:

```
if (str.Length != 0 && str[0] == 'V' && str[str.Length-1] == ']') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var startChar = char(86).ToString();
var endChar = char(91).ToString();

if (myString.StartsWith(startCar) && myString.EndsWith(endChar))
{
    ....
}
```

Or to tidy that up implement your own extension methods for `StartWith`/`EndWith` on type string which takes chars:

```
public static string StartsWith(this string str, char ch)
{
     return str.StartsWith(ch.ToString());
}
```

Then your code would just look like:

```
myString.StartsWith(char(86)) && myString.EndsWith(char(91))
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking a character by its ASCII value in a string is for the most part one in the same with checking the actual character value. However, to enlighten you:

```
string s = "V4-42$TIh[";

if (s[0] == 86 && s[s.Length - 1] == 91) {
    // true
}
```

No need to do anything special or even use function calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `System.Convert.ToInt32("Yourstring"[0])`. Pass the character of your string till its length like :

```
string Yourstring="test";
string asciivalue="";
```

Do the following till the length of the

```
asciivalue=System.Convert.ToInt32("Yourstring"[i]);
```

This will output the corresponding ASCII value..